# "should" and "should be" in "He should get the role" and "The role should be given to him"

Tags: active-vs-passive

Is there a difference between:

> He should get the role

and

> The role should be given to him

Answer (score 1):

The statements mean the same thing.
Looking at the structure of the statements you can see:

"He should get the role" = [Who] should [object]

Whereas, "The role should be given to him" = [Object] should [Who].

The reason 'He should *be* the role doesn't work is because logically, someone can't be a position. You need to connect him and the role. You can use 'He should be given the role' where 'be given' is the same as 'get' **in this case**.

Additionally, referring to the second statement; you can say 'The role should *get* given to him'. However, that isn't best practice, and some might say that it is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

As another user said, the two sentences technically have the same meaning. However, there is a subtle difference in that the first sentence is in the "active voice" and the second sentence is in the "passive voice."

The first sentence clearly states who ought to be doing something ("He") and what they should be doing (getting the role). It also suggests that the person seeking the role is taking action to get it.

In the second sentence, the person is not doing something, he is having something done to him. This could result in him having the role without doing anything at all — the outcome will be determined by someone else.

It's also important to note that this sentence does not specify who should be giving him the role, but it does require that there is someone doing the giving. The passive voice makes the statement feel uncertain.

You could restate the second sentence in the active voice by saying, "Someone should give him the role." Even though the specific party doing the giving is still unknown, this phrasing suggest that their identity is not important to the point being made.

Many grammar guides will advise writers to avoid the passive voice because the active voice is more clear and direct, but it is not grammatically incorrect to use it.

If you want to learn more about how these voices are used in writing, I recommend this [Grammarly article about the Active and Passive voice](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/active-vs-passive-voice/)